# Which meta tags before title tag in html with doctype 4.01 Transitional?

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta

So my question is about which meta tags are placed before the title tag when set in the head tag in html with doctype 4.01 Transitional.

Here I give an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Index</title>
   <meta name="keywords" content="whatsoever">
   <meta name="description" content="ask stackoverflow">
   <meta name="author" content="gugol">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/nicestyles.css">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I think I should have the charset attribute first so that everything in the html document is read under the character encoding for the HTML document. But have some doubts about the others.

What would be just the right order??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers let you specify the character encoding in a `meta` tag so that it is applied even to elements preceding it. However, such a tag should appear as early as possible according to HTML 4.01, clause [5.2.2 Specifying the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2). HTML5 CR clarifies further, in clause [4.2.5.5 Specifying the document's character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset), that “the element containing the character encoding declaration must be serialized completely within the first 1024 bytes of the document”.

The point here is that unless the encoding has been specified in HTTP headers or by data interpretable as Byte Order Mark at the start of a document, the browser will scan some initial part, such as one kilobyte, of the document, then infer or guess the encoding from it, tentatively parsing it as Ascii data and recognizing a `meta` tag if there is one.

Other than this, no order restrictions are placed on the content of a `head` element, and there is no reason to expect that the order of `meta` elements would matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right order. Your title and meta tags can be in any order and the results will be the same.

Comment: What if I have in my title special characters that require validation as soon as possible?

Comment: They won't be validated or have anything else done until after at least all of the items in the `<head>` are parsed and the browser knows what it is working with.

Comment: So, the meta charset tag should be placed before the title tag if the title tag contains special characters.
Like in this example:

`<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>España</title>
   <meta name="keywords" content="whatsoever">
   <meta name="description" content="ask stackoverflow">
   <meta name="author" content="gugol">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/nicestyles.css">
</head>`

Comment: Doesn't matter. It will look for the charset before it starts to do anything with text